# From array of paths to object using reduce and recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I need to convert an array of paths:

```
const paths = [
  "test1",
  "test1.test1children"
]
```

to an object with the following structure:

```
{
  name: "test1",
  id: "test1",
  children: [...test1 children],
}
```

I try with a reducer and a recursive function per array item, it is works but is pretty slow. Any suggestions to improve this code are welcome. Thanks in advance.

```js
  const iterRow = (row, obj) => {
    if (Array.isArray(row) && row.length !== 0) {
      const [name, ...pathStack] = row;
      const found = (n) => obj.children.find((i) => i.name === n);

      if (obj.name === name) {
        iterRow(pathStack, obj);
      } else {
        const newLeaf = {
          name,
          id: `${obj.id}.${name}`,
          children: [],
        };
        if (!found(name)) {
          obj.children.push(newLeaf);
        }
        iterRow(pathStack, found(name));
      }
    }
  };
  
const argOptionsProcessed = (rows) => rows.reduce((acc, row) => {
    const path = row.split('.');
    const found = () => acc.find((item) => path[0] === item.name);
    if (!found()) {
      acc.push({ name: path[0], id: path[0], children: [] });
    }
    iterRow(path, found());
    return acc;
  }, []);
  
  
  
const paths = [
"test1",
"test1.test1children",
"test1.test1children.test1subchildren",
"test1.test1children.test1subchildren.test1subsubchildren",
"tets2",
"test2.test2children",
]


console.log(argOptionsProcessed(paths));
```

Comment: This question may be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Btw i am not sure if your code is working. I get back 3 instead of 2 objects. The object with id `test2` is contained twice.

Comment: And better provide an abstract explanation of the algorithm you used, so people can help you improving this algorithm and have not to understand your whole code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this without recursion using `forEach` and `reduce` methods and one object to keep nested levels.

```js
const paths = [
  "test1",
  "test1.test1children",
  "test1.test1children.test1subchildren",
  "test1.test1children.test1subchildren.test1subsubchildren",
  "test2",
  "test2.test2children",
]

const result = []
const levels = { result }

paths.forEach(path => {
  let id = '';

  path.split('.').reduce((r, name, i, a) => {
    id += (id ? '.' : '') + name;

    if (!r[name]) {
      r[name] = { result: [] }
      r.result.push({ name, id, children: r[name].result })
    }

    return r[name]
  }, levels)
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: You are right! thank you very much! ill try in my own code thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could take a shorter approach by reducing the array and the path and search for same name.

```js
const
    getTree = data => data.reduce((tree, path) => {
        path.split('.').reduce((t, name, i, a) => {
            let temp = t.find(q => q.name === name);
            if (!temp) t.push(temp = { name, id: a.slice(0, i + 1).join('.'), children: [] });
            return temp.children;
        }, tree);
        return tree;
    }, []),
    paths = ["test1", "test1.test1children", "test1.test1children.test1subchildren", "test1.test1children.test1subchildren.test1subsubchildren", "tets2", "test2.test2children"]

console.log(getTree(paths));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution.

```js
const paths = [
  "test1",
  "test1.test1children",
  "test1.test1children.test1subchildren",
  "test1.test1children.test1subchildren.test1subsubchildren",
  "test2",
  "test2.test2children",
];

console.log(untangle(paths));

function untangle(paths) {
  return paths.reduce( (a, v) => {
    const path = v.split(".");
    if (path.length < 2) {
      const l0 = path[0];
      let level0 = {name: l0, id: l0, children: []};
      let tryChildren = paths
        .filter( p => ~p.indexOf(".") && p.startsWith(l0) )
      if (tryChildren.length) {
        tryChildren = tryChildren.map( p => p.substr( p.indexOf(".")+1 ) );
        level0.children = level0.children.concat(untangle(tryChildren));
      }
      a.push(level0);
    }
    return a;
  }, []);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```